# Making a loop for a simple Python program

Tags: python

So my professor is asking me to code and make a word dictionary, which I have completed with just 5 words, but I can add more. The only problem is that I need a loop function. If I run my program it only runs once then exits. It only prompts the user to input the word they are searching for once and whether or not it is wrong the program will just end itself. Here is my code :

```
#This dictionary has only five words : "virus" , "umami", "plethora", "pandemic" and "python"

dictionary = {"virus" : "A virus is a sub-microscopic infectious agent that replicates only inside the living cells of a organism.", "pandemic" : "A pandemic is a disease that has spread around the globe", "plethora" : "A large or excessive amount of something", "umami" : "A fifth taste that mostly describes a pleasant savoury taste", "python" : "It is a high level programming language"}

search = input("Search: ").casefold()



if search in dictionary:
    word = search.title()
    print("{} - {}".format(word, dictionary[search]))
else:
    print("Keyword not found")
```

Comment: This question is not very clear at all. What would you like the program to actually do? once you can explain that, then people can actually help.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, my prof seems to be sick of students asking her questions which is why I came here, I'm not sure what shes asking me to do also but she told my to make a program that acts like a word dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
>>> string = '1'
>>> while string == '1':
    search = input("Enter your search: ")
    if search in dictionary:
        word = search.title()
        print("{}  -  {}".format(word, dictionary[search]))
    else:
        print("Keyword not found")
    string = input("Enter 1 to continue and 0 to exit: ")


Enter your search: d
Keyword not found
Enter 1 to continue and 0 to exit: 1
Enter your search: python
Python  -  It is a high level programming language
Enter 1 to continue and 0 to exit: 0
>>>
```

Comment: Three suggestions: 1) Change `string` to something else.  `string` is the name of a built-in libary.  2) Replace your `while string == 1` loop with a `while True` loop; then flag to `False` when you want to exit.  This will simplify your code and remove the need to a `string` variable. 3) Control the case of your `search` variable in a way that the term will be found regardless of cAsE.

Comment: I would certainly like to change the string (actually I was just giving a sample) but replacing while string == 1 with while True is as good as earlier.